# Empilhar dados de uma lista no pandas

Tags: pandas

Estou tentando empilhar vários arquivos em csv que estão listados em um tipo de arquivo csv, porém quando aplico a iteração sobre eles eu só visualizo o último arquivo.

Segue o código.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 lista = pd.read_csv('lista.csv') - (neste arquivo contém a lista com o nome dos arquivos dentro da pasta em csv)


 lista = lista['.ipynb_checkpoints'].values.tolist()

 for i in lista:
     i = pd.read_csv(i,sep=';')

print(i)
```

Eu queria salvar uma variavel com cada arquivo da lista, para depois empilhar todos eles.

Obrigado pela ajuda,

Abraços,

Answer (score 0):

Tentou usar list comprehension? Me parece que seu código não está muito adequado para realizar a terefa pretendida. Tente trocar este seu `for` pelo seguinte

```
l = [pd.read_csv(i,sep=';') for i in lista]
```

no fim, `l` vai conter uma lista com todos os dataFrames que você deseja, uma vez que você tenha se certificado que a variável `lista` contém as strings com os nomes dos arquivos adequados.

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!